# Getting Wrong Total output?

Tags: sql-server

Example

I want to calculate the worktime between 09:00:00 to 18:00:00,

```
09:00:00 - Normal_Intime
18:00:00 - Normal_Outtime
```

Suppose

```
1) Intime is 10:00:00, Outtime is 17:00:00 It should give the output as 07:00:00
2) Intime is 08:00:00. Outtime is 19:00:00 It should give the output as 09:00:00
```

above output should compare with Normal_Intime, Normal_Outtime .

Means Normal_Intime is 09:00:00 only and Normal_Output is 18:00:00 only, so Intime should not > 09:00:00 and Outtime < 18:00:00.

Query

```
select Intime, Outtime, CONVERT(char(8), CASE WHEN OutTime > Normal_Outtime THEN cast(Normal_Outtime AS datetime) ELSE cast(OutTime AS datetime) END - CASE WHEN InTime > Normal_Intime THEN cast(InTime AS datetime) ELSE cast(Normal_Intime AS datetime) END, 8) AS WorkTime from table
```

Output

```
Intime       Outtime        Worktime
15:37:48    22:08:15    02:22:12
07:33:34    07:59:13    22:59:13
```

the Second Row giving wrong output It should give only 00:25:39

If both in and out time is smaller than NormalInTime and both in and out time is greater than NormalOutTime. How to make a condtion for this

How to make a query for this conditon.

Need Query Help.

Comment: How do you come to “09:00:00” in your second example? What exactly is the number you’re trying to get supposed to express?

Comment: Your example does not make sense. In the second row, both in and out is smaller than NormalInTime...

Comment: @astander. That what i asked a condtion for both in and out is smaller than NormalInTime and both in and out is greater than NormalOutTime. How to make a condtion for this.

Comment: I gave an answer below for these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        InTime DATETIME,
        OutTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table (InTime,OutTime) SELECT '15:37:48', '22:08:15'
INSERT INTO @Table (InTime,OutTime) SELECT '07:33:34', '07:59:13'

DECLARE @Normal_InTime DATETIME,
        @Normal_OutTime DATETIME

SELECT  @Normal_InTime = '09:00:00',
        @Normal_OutTime = '18:00:00'

SELECT  *,
        --both dates are smaller than NotmalInTime
        CASE
            WHEN InTime < @Normal_InTime AND OutTime < @Normal_InTime THEN OutTime - InTime
            WHEN OutTime > @Normal_OutTime AND InTime > @Normal_OutTime THEN OutTime - InTime
            WHEN OutTime > @Normal_OutTime 
                THEN @Normal_OutTime - InTime
            WHEN InTime < @Normal_InTime
                THEN OutTime - @Normal_InTime
            ELSE OutTime - InTime
        END
FROM    @Table
```

But you need to take into account. What happens when the user books in before 24:00 and then books out the next day.

And as i said, what happens in the event that book in and bookout is either before NormalTimeIn or after NormalTimeOut?

you need to specify this.

Comment: Works for me - also handles scenario where InTime and OutTime are greater than Normal_OutTime

Answer (score 1):

YOU SHOULD CONSIDER THE DATE ALSO WHILE CALCULATING THE TIME.

```
declare 
@Normal_Intime datetime,
@Normal_Outtime datetime,
@Actual_Intime datetime,
@Actual_Outtime datetime
set @Normal_Intime = cast('09:00:00' as datetime)
set @Normal_Outtime =cast('18:00:00' as datetime) 

-- CASE 1
set @Actual_Outtime = cast('17:00:00' as datetime)  
set @Actual_Intime = cast('10:00:00' as datetime)  

select case when @Actual_Intime > @Normal_Intime then @Actual_Intime else @Normal_Intime end -
case when @Actual_Outtime < @Normal_Outtime then @Actual_Outtime else @Normal_Outtime end

-- CASE 2    

set @Actual_Outtime = cast('19:00:00' as datetime)    
set @Actual_Intime = cast('08:00:00' as datetime)    

select case when @Actual_Intime > @Normal_Intime then @Actual_Intime else @Normal_Intime end -
case when @Actual_Outtime < @Normal_Outtime then @Actual_Outtime else @Normal_Outtime end

-- CASE 3  

set @Actual_Outtime = cast('07:59:13' as datetime)    
set @Actual_Intime = cast('07:33:34' as datetime)    

select case when @Actual_Intime > @Normal_Intime then @Actual_Intime else @Normal_Intime end -
case when @Actual_Outtime < @Normal_Outtime then @Actual_Outtime else @Normal_Outtime end
```

Comment: hmmm - not working for me either (tried FF and IE) looks like a problem with SO

Comment: then how can i answer this question

Comment: The indenting doesn't seem to work but adding a backtick at the start and and of each line does - try that.

Comment: thanks dilbert, but its messed up the code. gopal try removing the single quote and execute the query hope its helpful

Comment: Yo've used a ' instead of a ` (normally top left - above tab key on UK keyboard)

Comment: Ah found the 'glitch' - try adding a blank line before the first line of code and then indent the code by 4 characters. That seems to work ok for me. Odd, I'm sure it never used to be like that.

Comment: @solairaja, just to let you know, I removed the downvote. I thought you were being pedantic (after your second edit) but as it turns out, you just seemed to be struggling with the SO editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, Outtime - Intime, 108) FROM YourTable
```

`Outtime - Intime` will give you a timespan that you want and convert with `108` parameter will give you just hours, minutes and seconds from that timespan [more info about convert](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_1.htm)

Comment: @RaYell. Am Not asked the Conversion, i asked only the case condition. Please read my question.